# D3.js zoom: discrete scales of heatmap do not update

Tags: javascript, zooming, d3.js

I am very new to D3 and I hope you can help me.
I have a basic heatmap to visualize gene expression data with conditions/treatments on xAxis and genes on yAxis, so 2 discrete scales (scaleBands).
Now I want to add a `d3.zoom()` function as shown below:

```
  const extent = [[margin.left, margin.top], [width - margin.right, height - margin.top]];

  svg.call(d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1, 8])
      .translateExtent(extent)
      .extent(extent)
      .on("zoom", updateChart));
  function updateChart() {
    ////PROBLEM ZOOM WITH SCALEBAND
    // new x Scale
    x.range([margin.left, width - margin.right].map(d => d3.event.transform.applyX(d)));
    svg.selectAll("#cell").attr("x", d => x(d.condition)).attr("width", x.bandwidth());
    svg.selectAll("xAxisG").call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    // new y Scale
    y.range([height - margin.bottom, margin.top].map(d => d3.event.transform.applyY(d)))
    svg.selectAll("#cell").attr("y", d => y(d.gene)).attr("height", y.bandwidth());
    svg.selectAll("yAxisG").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  }
```

(code see https://github.com/NicolaiNi/Omiqa.bioProjects)
So zooming in general works but the update of the x and y Axis does not.
How can I update the axis depending on the zooming level?

See picture below:
[after zooming x and y axis disappear and do not update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCLN9.png)